# Unable to connect to Mlab.com database from AWS EC2 instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mlab

I am trying to connect to my MongoDB instance hosted on http://mlab.com from AWS EC2 instance.

```
$ mongo ds023495.mlab.com:23495/db -u username -p password
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: ds023495.mlab.com:23495/db
2016-11-29T08:01:14.014+0000 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1287
exception: login failed
```

But if I try to do it from my local machine, it is able to connect to same database.

What's going wrong with EC2 instance?
Do I need to whitelist some protocols or ports from AWS Security Groups?

Comment: Does your EC2 server have Internet access? Does it have a public IP address? Have you created any outbound rules in the security group assigned to the EC2 instance?

Comment: Hi, the EC2 instance does have public IP address. I have created inbound rules, but I haven't created outbound rules.

Comment: I got the same problem. Have you solved this issue yet?

Comment: Well, my problem is I forgot the change the url to the mongodb, so it was still the url to the local mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the mongo shell version on the EC2 instance is the same major release or higher as the MongoDB server you're connecting to.